# Could not load file or assembly 'Remotion.Linq, Version=2.1.0.0

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

In my C# project when I call this code:

```
var erg = (from p in m_dbSession.Query<VBESelectionTracker>()
          where p.ModuleName.Equals(newSelection.ModuleName) && p.DatabaseFile.Equals(m_dbFile)
          select p).ToList();
```

the following exception is thrown:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Remotion.Linq, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fee00910d6e5f53b' or one of its dependencies.
```

A "Remotion.Linq.dll" is part of the build, but when I look into its properties, the version is: 2.2.0.30000. This is not suprising because v2.2.0 is the Version of Remotion.Linq which I installed via NuGet. I also use FluentNHibernate v2.1.2 and NHibernate v5.1.1 (I have to use a old version of NHibernate because of this: https://github.com/FluentNHibernate/fluent-nhibernate/issues/430 bug).

So which part of my program tries to use Remotion.Linq v2.1.0.0 and why? What can I do to fix that?

Steps I have take to fix this:

- Installed NHibernate 5.1.5 => Same problem
- Try to downgrade to Remotion.Linq v2.1.1 (There is no 2.1.0) => As a consequence of this: FluentNHibernate is downgraded to v2.0.3 and NHibernate is downgraded to 4.1.2.4000 which causes a lot of other problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FluentNhibernate` has no dependencies on `Remotion.Linq`. So all dependencies issues between `NHibernate` and `Remotion.Linq`.

So simply remove all three nuget packages and then install them in the following order:

1) NHibernate 5.1.6 (it should install proper Remotion.Linq version, don't install it manually)

2) FluentNHibernate v2.1.2

Comment: Worked fine. Thanks!